How to identify and extract field data in log files in ELK
We have many disparate (some node, some tomcat, some Spring) services which provide rest API to other services or web apps.
Each service writes logs which are pulled into ELK.
Log entries are unstructured, but most start with the date, and most have INFO/ERROR etc.
Elk doesn't understand what's in the log lines, you can only search on keyword. You cant even search using the log files time stamp, as ELK stores its @timestmap field as when the log file was ingested, not the time stamp of the log line in question.  Elk has no concept of fields like a database would, its just a list of strings.
Today I notice ELK has concept of rollups and downsampling which implies there is a data field (such as elapsedTime or errorCode) to aggregate.   The various documentation pages show these fields as already existing. Where do they come from?
E.g. this page: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.13/downsampling.html
shows a field called cpu.idle.ticks
Assuming there is a way to create "fields" out of unstructured raw logs, what is the best practice?
E.g. I would guess we want to create a global field data dictionary which devs have to use in their log lines, such as "myapp-cpu-idle-ticks-field" then there is some sort of pattern matching looking for myapp-cpu-idle-ticks-field:123 anywhere in any log line.  However, this leads to two problems:

typos, such as myapp-cpu-idle-ticks-field=123 or myapp-cpu-idle-ticks-field: 123 or cpuIdleTicks:1234
if you have a typo, you will never know, and the data is lost.

